# Drupal 7: Fatal Error undefined db_fetch_object()

Tags: php, drupal-7

PHP Fatal error:

```
Call to undefined function db_fetch_object() in /var/www/testsite/sites/all/modules/contrib/flashvideo/flashvideo.module on line 2092, in Drupal 7 when I upgarded my website from drupal 6 to 7.
```

Query is:

```
$sql = "SELECT fv.oid, f.filepath, fv.width, fv.height, f.fid FROM {flashvideo} fv
         LEFT JOIN {files} f ON f.fid = fv.fid
         LEFT JOIN {upload} u on u.fid = fv.fid
         WHERE $flashmime AND (fv.status = %d) AND (fv.nid = %d) AND (fv.video_index =   %d)$vid_query";
  $video_file = db_fetch_object(db_query($sql, FLASHVIDEO_STATUS_CONVERTED, $nid, $index, $node->vid));
```

How should I write query? Should I need to change query?

Comment: In drupal 6 upload module was in Core modules, but in drupal 7 it is removed. but in above query upload table is used, what should we do for that?

Answer (score 3):

I guess db_fetch_object is [deprecated](https://drupal.org/node/1034288) from drupal 7.

Instead try,

```
db_query($sql, FLASHVIDEO_STATUS_CONVERTED, $nid, $index, $node->vid)->fetch();
```

Comment: Have you got any solution ? Is this answer helps you ?